# SQL Server 2012 paging returns wrong result

Tags: sql-server-2012, paging

I have a prolem with paging in SQL Server 2012

This is a simple table to test:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Code] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Type] [int] NULL,
    [IsActive] [bit] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TestTable] 
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ON 
GO

INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (1, N'1', N'1', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (2, N'2', N'2', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (3, N'3', N'3', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (4, N'4', N'4', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (5, N'5', N'5', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (6, N'6', N'6', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (7, N'7', N'7', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (8, N'8', N'8', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (9, N'9', N'9', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (10, N'10', N'10', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (11, N'11', N'11', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (12, N'12', N'12', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (13, N'13', N'13', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (14, N'14', N'14', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (15, N'15', N'15', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (16, N'16', N'16', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (17, N'17', N'17', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (18, N'18', N'18', 1, 1)
INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] ([ID], [Name], [Code], [Type], [IsActive]) 
VALUES (19, N'19', N'19', 1, 1)
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TestTable] OFF
GO
```

Here some screenshots :

All records:

[image]

Try to paging, page 1:

[image]

and page 2:

[image]

Some records dont appear on both pages.

What do I need to do to correct this?

Thanks a lot

Comment: SQL Server 2012 works just fine - you're asking for the **first 20 rows** in your first query, for the **first 10 rows** in your second query - **of course** you'll see some rows duplicated! Check the [official documentation for `OFFSET...FETCH`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg699618%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) and fix your queries !

Comment: You don't my point when showing 3 pictures
The first picture, I just want to show all records (19 records, and order by Type)
The second and the third pictures are the prolem.
They do not cover all the records of the table

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the **first 10 rows**, then use:

```
SELECT (columns)
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY [Type], ID 
    OFFSET 0 ROWS 
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

and for the **next 10 rows**, use:

```
SELECT (columns)
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY [Type], ID 
    OFFSET 10 ROWS    -- you need to properly set the OFFSET !!
    FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

The features works just fine - you haven't gotten your syntax quite right, that's all.

**Update:** ordering by *only* `[Type]` is not good enough - if you have lots of rows with the same value of `[Type]`, there's no guaranteed ordering within that group of rows. You need to include something more useful into your ordering, e.g. by using the primary key (which is **unique** per row and therefore clearly establishes an ordering). I updated my response to use `[Type], ID` for ordering

Comment: But I do the same as your sample...
I want to show first 10 rows, order by [Type], not ID
I show 3 picture with same order by clause
And they miss some records.

Comment: @haiduong87: `ORDER BY Type` is a bit useless if the rows **ALL** contain the value 1 - that's not a specific enough ordering .....

Comment: But the point is: if **all** those rows have the same `Type`, then there's no real defined ordering possible. Your `ORDER BY` is just inconclusive. Try ordering by `ID` - it **WORKS**, doesn't it? It's not **SQL Server 2012 paging** that's not working ....

Comment: Thanks, many other told me to do that too :)
I will add ID for better paging (must confirm with supervisor)
Thanks alot :D